# problema al acceder a propiedad de la data de una peticion get en axios me da error

Tags: ajax, json, vue.js, axios, nativescript

estoy haciendo una peticion get con axios el problema es que al leer la propiedad del json obtenido me sale undefined, estoy usando php slim en el servidor como api, del lado del cliente es una app movil con nativescript-vue les dejo el codigo para que vean cual es el error

codigo slim php

```
$app->get('/getToken', function ($request, $response, $args) {
// CSRF token name and value
$nameKey = $this->csrf->getTokenNameKey();
$valueKey = $this->csrf->getTokenValueKey();
$name = $request->getAttribute($nameKey);
$value = $request->getAttribute($valueKey);


$arreglo=array("namekey"=>$name ,"valuekey"=>$value);
$response->write(json_encode($arreglo,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
});
```

el codigo en el cliente

```
function GetToken(){
console.log("entramos en getToken");

       axios.get("http://tallerinternet.esy.es/getToken").then(respuesta=>{

                console.log(respuesta.data);

                console.log(respuesta.data.namekey);
      }).catch(function (error) {
           // handle error
          console.log("error " + error); 
        }); 
 }
```

al hacer el console.log(respuesta.data) me muestra la estructura del json

```
{
  "namekey":"csrf5b9975d057d61",
  "valuekey":"63b5e0e720bffd5a8ccad0257d61ff62"
}
```

pero al intentar imprimir la propiedad con console.log(respuesta.data.namekey) me da undefined,

puede ser que me falte algo al hacer la peticion con axios

en este link se encuentra lo que tiene respuesta que proviene del servidor
https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=de958d43b38b4164bf3544bb24110fe3 pero si ocupo el modulo http que viene por defecto en la data no aparecen los slash.

Comment: Intentastes acceder a ella asi? : console.log(respuesta.data["namekey"]);

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav me sale igual el error

Comment: EL axios lo tienes bien sino te falla hasta el `respuesta.data`, es raro se que colocastes lo que te devuelve el `respuesta.data` pero podrias colocar un print de eso? es para ver si no se te esta escapando algo mas, un print de la respuesta del console.log por favor

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav aca esta lo que contiene data https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=de958d43b38b4164bf3544bb24110fe3  no lo quise poner aca estaba muy desordenado y alli se puede ver mejor

Comment: OK intenta quitarle al `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` json_encode pruebas y me avisas

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav le saque JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES   y sigue igual

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav es una configuración del axios por que hice la petición con el modulo http que viene con vue.js y funciono ahora el problema es que este modulo solo tiene get y post para hacer request y yo necesito ademas para request put y delete cosa que tiene axios

Comment: por favor intenta lo que te dije, haz un json_encode sin JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES.

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav ya lo hice y sigue igual

Comment: que raro igual coloque una respuesta a ver si te resultaba, que lastima jumm dejame seguir indgando

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav es slim por que probe con un archivo sin slim y el json no trae backslash, el problema es que todavia no encuentro como sacar los backslash en slim.

Comment: cuando dices slim es el framework de php?

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav si el framework slim php para crear api restfull

Comment: Ok trata de colocar la respuesta asi: $response->withStatus(200)->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')->write(json_encode($arreglo)); si no funciona agregale el JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, me comentas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83140/discussion-between-jose-miguel-jara-and-david-leonardo-molina-ruiz-dav).

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes en la opción **JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES** del **json_encode**, fijate como lo trae según el codigo que compartistes [aquí](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=de958d43b38b4164bf3544bb24110fe3) y fijate como serian sin esa opción:

```js
var response = {
  data: {
         "namekey":"csrf5b998483cf2bc",
         "valuekey":"cfc55cd6bbf20704fe09472a6a1e986a"
        }
}

console.log(response)
console.log(response.data)
console.log(response.data.namekey)
```